# Why 1 is not a cluster point of $\frac1n$

Tags: real-analysis

I came across this definition of cluster point. Let $S \subset R$ be a set. A number $x \in \mathbb R$ is called a cluster point of $S$ if for every
$\varepsilon > 0$, the set $(x−ε, x+ε)∩S \setminus \{x\}$ is not empty.

For the set $\{1/n:n∈\mathbb N\}$ why 1 is not a cluster point?
I came across this proof while googling but still cant understand it

http://mathonline.wikidot.com/cluster-points

Suppose that $0<c≤1$. By one of the Archimedean corollaries, since $1c>0$ then there exists a natural number $n_c\in\mathbb N$ such that $n_c−1≤1c<n_c$ and so $1n_c<c≤1n_c−1$. Choose $δ_0=\min\{∣c−1n_c∣,∣1n_c−1−c∣\}. Then $Vδ(c)={x∈\mathbb R:∣x−c∣<\min{∣c−1n_c∣,∣1n_c−1−c∣}}=∅$.

I take $n_c=10, c=1$, then delta is 0.888888889. I can find an $x=0.5$ such that the inequality satisfies. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to visit http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference, right now the question is hardly understandable.

Comment: 1 isn't a cluster point because it doesn't fit the definition for any epsilon less than 1/2.  The nearest 1/n to 1 is an entire 1/2 unit away.  1/n s do not cluster around 1.  They don't even come close to the 1.

Comment: To be a cluster point, the condition must be true for *all* epsilon greater than 0.  Not just a specific epsilon.  delta = .88888889 is a very large delta.  You have to show it also is true for delta =.00000001. can you?  You have to show it is true for delta = $10^{-100}$.  Can you?

Answer (score 2):

A number x∈R is called a cluster point of S if for *!!!!!EVERY!!!!!* ε>0, the set (x−ε,x+ε)∩S∖{x} is not empty.

So if $\epsilon = 2/3$ then, yes, $(1 - \epsilon = 1/3, 1 + \epsilon = 1 2/3)\cap \{1/n\} / \{1\} =\{1/2\}$ is not empty.  Fine but we need to show that for *!!!!!EVERY!!!!!!* epsilon.

Let $\epsilon \le 1/2$ then $(1 - \epsilon \ge 1/2, 1 + \epsilon )\cap \{1/n\} / \{1\}$ *is* empty.  So one is not a cluster point.

Answer (score 1):

If we take $\epsilon$ to be $.25$ and we have $S = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, then $(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon) \cap S = (.75,1.25) \cap S = 1,$ so $1$ is not a cluster point.